# How to link multiple Query Operations in MongoDb C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create a complex query expression with the MongoDb C# driver. So far I've mostly relied on the LINQ .AsQueryable() features which work great, but now I need to run some update operations and it looks like I need to use the QueryBuilder for that.

However, I can't figure out how to create a complex query that strings multiple query operators together.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var query = Query<QueueMessageItem>
            .EQ( qi => qi.Type, queueName)
            .EQ("Started", null);
```

but apparently this doesn't work because .EQ() and all the other query operators don't return a chainable Query object.

How do I use Queries and add multiple search operators?

Comment: Have you tried nesting them (`Query.Or(Query.EQ("t", "F"), Query.EQ("t", "M"))`)?

Comment: Nope - and I missed it because Query<T> doesn't have it. Yes that'll work, but shame that the driver can't chain which would be way more natural.

Comment: Agreed, on fluent chaining.  BTW, love your blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the query operators.  Something like this

```
Query.Or(Query.EQ("t", "F"), Query.EQ("t", "M"))
```